# Selenium: Select by CSS Seelctor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying to click the submit button on WhitePages.com.

I tried:

```
div//buttom.submit.btn.btn-primary.inser.expandable")).submit();;
```

I also tried:

```
div//buttom.submit.btn.btn-primary.inser.expandable")).submit();;
```

And:

```
buttom.submit.btn.btn-primary.inser.expandable")).click();
```

None of the above code worked. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your specific html code so that people would find it easy to find the solution.

Comment: Never mind I found the answer

Comment: Can you post your actual code

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you're using a mix of XPath and CSS selectors.

To select the "Search" button you could use the CSS selector:

```
button.submit
```

or if you want to use all the classes (I wouldn't recommend it):

```
button.submit.btn-btn-primary.inset.expandable
```

**TIP:**
If you're having trouble finding the correct CSS Selector open up your console (in Chrome just press F12). WhitePages has jQuery loaded so if you type in:

```
$('button.submit')
```

You will notice that the element is indeed present.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. However, when I submit form WhitePages displays pop up saying "Your opinion is important to us" - Is this an IFrame or is it part of the actual page? I want to select "No" automatically.

Comment: I tried to replicate, but was never asked for my opinion. It sounds like it could be a modal (like this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

In order to determine whether or not you where asked your opinion you should look into Waits in Selenium, especially 

    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElement